# How to modify custom aspx page when main solution package (wsp) is missing

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-server, visual-studio, aspx

I have a SharePoint site. "http://partner.acompany.com/_layouts/account/dhy/createsite.aspx". I have to modify the custom page i.e. createsite.aspx page. The main problem is that there is no whereabouts of the main solution package that whether it is updated one or not.

So, I created a new solution and try to copy only the createsite.aspx page and its .cs in this new solution and try to build it in Visual Studio, but as usual it has some dependancy thats why failing. 
Please suggest some other approach. Or Is the main solution package still required?